# How to filtering a list of names from Python when querying through SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My original query is like

```
select table1.id, table1.value
from some_database.something table1
join some_set table2 on table2.code=table1.code
where table1.date_ >= :_startdate and table1.date_ <= :_enddate
```

which is saved in a string in Python. If I do

```
x = session.execute(script_str, {'_startdate': start_date, '_enddate': end_date})
```

then

```
x.fetchall()
```

will give me the table I want.

Now the situation is, table2 is no longer available to me in the Oracle database, instead it is available in my python environment as a DataFrame. I wonder what is the best way to fetch the same table from the database in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the `IN` clause instead.**

First remove the `join` from the `script_str`:

```
script_str = """
select  table1.id, table1.value
from    something table1
where   table1.date_ >= :_startdate and table1.date_ <= :_enddate
"""
```

Then, get codes from dataframe:

```
codes = myDataFrame.code_column.values
```

Now, we need to dynamically extend the `script_str` and the parameters to the query:

```
param_names = ['_code{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(codes))]
script_str += "AND table1.code IN ({})".format(
    ", ".join([":{}".format(p) for p in param_names])
)
```

Create dict with all parameters:

```
params = {
    '_startdate': start_date,
    '_enddate': end_date,
}
params.update(zip(param_names, codes))
```

And execute the query:

```
x = session.execute(script_str, params)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Only problem is that the maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 so I need to run multiple number of queries.

Comment: Yes, there is a limitation. If I remember correctly, the `IN` clause is not the best option from performance point of view. Depending on indices in your database, you might want to split it even smaller chunks.